# Windows 10 ping not resolving name but nslookup does

Tags: windows-10, dns, ping, nslookup

I have a windows 10 machine that is exhibiting some odd behaviour.  When I try and devices on my network by name they fail to resolve.

However a `ping -a` of the iPaddress will resolve to the correct name.

Nslookup works by both name and ipaddress.

When I use a browser or try and ssh the connection will error if I use hostname, but work by ipaddress.

```
    C:\Users\benwh
λ ping -a 192.168.1.4

Pinging lexmark [192.168.1.4] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.4: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=254
Reply from 192.168.1.4: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=254
Reply from 192.168.1.4: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=254
Reply from 192.168.1.4: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=254

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.4:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Users\benwh
λ ping lexmark
Ping request could not find host lexmark. Please check the name and try again.

C:\Users\benwh
λ nslookup lexmark
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    lexmark
Address:  192.168.1.4


C:\Users\benwh
λ nslookup 192.168.1.4
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    lexmark
Address:  192.168.1.4
```

On a linux machine with the same settings provided by dhcp the ping runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

## ipconfig Man Page - Try this first

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ipconfig

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

## Ping Man Page - States resolution order is Host,DNS Server, NetBIOS

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ping

## Host Name Resolution Order - Outlines the order and steps to try

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/172218/microsoft-tcp-ip-host-name-resolution-order

My guess is the DNS Cache is reporting incorrect on the window machine.

Comment: I have tried flushing my dns cache numerous times and also I dont have anything in my host file.  The only dns server is the router on 192.168.1.1

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple DNS servers configured for the NIC, not all Windows network access will automatically use them. This can make things somewhat confusing when diagnosing DNS issues.

Specifically, `nslookup` only uses the first DNS server configured for the NIC (by default).

You can check the DNS servers, and their precedence, by drilling into the properties of the network adaptor. You can also list them using

```
ipconfig /all
```

And if you do have another local DNS server configured, and it has been working successfully until recently, programs accessing the network may attempt to use it—but it may currently not be working, giving the issue you describe. To check this, you may run `nslookup` against a specific DNS server using:

```
dnslookup lexmark SERVER
```

where SERVER is a server name or IP address.

Comment: I only have one DNS server configured which is my router the same as the other machines in the network.  Additionally i dont have any entries in the host file.  I have flushed the dns cache multiple times